# Is it possible to use `ng-click` inside of `.append`

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I am trying to call one method using angular which is placed inside of `.append`.
But the method is not called.Can I use `ng-click` inside `.append`?otherwise is there any alternative way to append element in angular?

```
var app=angular
.module('myApp',[])
.controller('myController',function($scope){

  $scope.clickMe = function(){
        $('.paragraph').append('<span ng-click="closeMe()"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>');
  }      
  $scope.closeMe = function(){
    alert("closed")
  }
})
```

Sample: https://jsfiddle.net/fjhbbnno/

Comment: You shouldn't be modifying the DOM from a controller. Put your content, and relevant logic, in the view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you'll have to do dynamic compilation to bind the angular directives like ng-click to your controller scope, something like

```
var el = '<span ng-click="closeMe()"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>';
var compiledElement = $compile(el)($scope);
```

Now you can append this like

```
$('.paragraph').append(compiledElement )
```

Don't forget to inject `$compile` service in your controller

Comment: Using dynamic compilation and modifying the DOM from a controller is major overkill for what OP is trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Check if this logic helps

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fjhbbnno/1/)

```
var app=angular.module('myApp',[])
        .controller('myController',function($scope){
            $scope.clicked = false;
          $scope.clickMe = function(){
                $scope.clicked = true;
          }      
          $scope.closeMe = function(){
            alert("closed")
          }
        })
```

HTML:

```
<section ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController" ng-init="init()">
<div class="paragraph">
<p>
This is a sample.
</p>
<span ng-if="clicked"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true" ng-click="closeMe()"></i></span>
</div>
<button ng-click="clickMe()">Add Close ICon</button>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the `ng-bind-html`

```
$scope.clickMe = function(){
      $scope.htmlCode= $sce.trustAsHtml('<span ng-click="closeMe()"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>'); 
}  

<p>
  This is a sample.
  <span ng-bind-html="htmlCode">
  </span>
</p>
```

also inject the `$sce` to the controller. [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/fjhbbnno/2/)

Comment: It is better to use ng-sanitize dependency with the $sce, because some html text  cannot be sanitized using trustAsHtml. had that issue not so long ago :)

Answer (score 1):

It is, but it is not the best practice. 
**Often it will not work as the element is not is scope range until it is created which is too late.**

Angular has very particular set of rules that were made to keep it 'clear' let's say. 
Another example is dependency injection, which means you cannot provide multiple dependencies between different modules with the same name, this is not very smart either, for if you have a main module, that other controllers just derive from him, declare all of your dependencies in the main module and keep your code clear.

**Solution:**

**1)** Create your close me button and keep it hidden, show it after you append your html.

**2)** Another solution is to create a popup that will contain the relevant info.

**3)** If you must append the ng-click, use the $compile dependency that will bring your directives to scope from the appended html:

```
 var compile = $compile(appendedElement)($scope)
```